# Removing All Leaves from a BinaryTree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

This method is supposed to remove all leaves from a binary (no left and right branches) tree, but for some reason, it only removes one instance of a leaf from the binary tree. Why is that? I though the base case is responsible for severing the ties the parent node by setting parent.left or parent.right to null. If it isn't a leaf, it would recursively call until it hits a leaf.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 private IntTreeNode overallRoot; // Beginning of the chain of nodes


    // post: Removes All leaves from a tree
     public void removeLeaves() {
     if (overallRoot == null) { // If empty tree
         return;
     } else {
         removeLeaves(overallRoot);
     }

 }

 // helper for removeLeaves
 private void removeLeaves(IntTreeNode root) {       
     if (root.left != null) { // tests left root
         if (root.left.left == null && root.left.right == null) { // if next left node is leaf (base case)
             root.left = null; // delete
         } else if (root.left.left != null && root.left.right == null) { // If next right is empty
             removeLeaves(root.left.left); // only check second left
         } else if (root.left.right != null && root.left.left == null) { // If next left is empty
             removeLeaves(root.left.right); 
         } else if (root.left.left != null && root.left.right != null) { // If next left/right isn't empty
             removeLeaves(root.left.left);
             removeLeaves(root.left.right);
         }
     }

     if (root.right != null) {
         if (root.right.left == null && root.right.right == null) { // if next left node is leaf (base case)
             root.right = null; // delete
         } else if (root.right.left != null && root.right.right == null) { // If next right is empty
             removeLeaves(root.right.left); // only check second left
         } else if (root.right.right != null && root.right.left == null) { // If next left is empty
             removeLeaves(root.right.right); 
         } else if (root.right.left != null && root.right.right != null) { // If next left/right isn't empty
             removeLeaves(root.right.left);
             removeLeaves(root.right.right);
         }
     }
 }
```

Here is the individual node class:

```
public class IntTreeNode {
     public int data;
     public IntTreeNode left;
     public IntTreeNode right;

     // constructs a leaf node with given data
     public IntTreeNode(int data) {
         this(data, null, null);
     }

     // constructs a branch node with given data, left subtree,
     // right subtree
     public IntTreeNode(int data, IntTreeNode left, IntTreeNode right) {
         this.data = data;
         this.left = left;
         this.right = right;
     }
}
```

Comment: Your problems are (1) that you're recursing down two levels at a time instead of only one; and (2) that you're never dealing with the case where `root` is itself a leaf node.  I strongly suggest that you step through this with a debugger, and see for yourself what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your recursive calls, instead of doing

```
removeLeaves(root.left.left);
```

you do

```
removeLeaves(root.left);
```

it should work. As Wallace points out in the comment, it looks like your're getting down two levels at a time. Also, the code could be reduced in the following way (the equivalent for the right tree)

```
if (root.left != null) { // tests left root
     if (root.left.left == null && root.left.right == null) { 
         root.left = null; // delete
     } else {
         removeLeaves(root.left);
     }
 }
```

Take into account also that this do not solve the problem of a **root** being itself a leave!

Answer (score 2):

Structural modification on trees is often cleaner when approached in a bottom-up manner:

```
public IntTreeNode removeLeaves(IntTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null || root.isLeaf()) {
        return null;
    }
    root.left = removeLeaves(root.left);
    root.right = removeLeaves(root.right);
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking too far ahead in each pass through the recursion. If the left has leaves, call removeLeaves(root.left). Do the same with the right. Then set left and right to null as needed.

I think this would do it:

```
public void removeLeaves(IntTreeNode root) {
if (root != null) {
    removeLeaves(root.left);
    removeLeaves(root.right);
    root.left = null;
    root.right = null;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will search the tree depth first and then remove the leaf nodes as encountered.

public class RemoveLeafNode {

```
public static void removeLeaves(Node root){
    if(root!=null){
        removeL(root.leftChild);
        removeL(root.rightChild);
    }
}

private static void removeL(Node node){
    if(node==null){
        return;
    }

    if(node.leftChild == null  && node.rightChild == null){
        node=null;//delete leaf
    }

    removeL(node.leftChild);
    removeL(node.rightChild);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

By using post-order traversal we can solve this problem (other traversals would also work).

```
struct BinaryTreeNode* removeLeaves(struct BinaryTreeNode* root) {
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        {
            free(root);
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            root->left = removeLeaves(root->left);
            root->right = removeLeaves(root->right);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Time Complexity: O(n). Where is number of nodes in tree.